# How can I align a TextView to the far left and ImageView to the far right in an Actionbar Spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-actionbar, spinner

I am trying to layout an actionbar spinner dropdown list. I have a textview and an imageview in each row. I want the textview to align to the far left of the dropdown (with the paddingLeft) and I want the imageview to align to the far right of the dropdown. The text in the textviews varies in length, so the icons end up being aligned to the immediate right of the textviews. This layout provides a two line item on the actionbar with the spinner title and selected item name.

Here is my current layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:contentDescription="icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried a relative layout like below, with similar results (see screen shot). The bluetooth icon is a stand in for the yet to be created icon (same size):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name"
        android:contentDescription="icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`, and use the alignParentLeft/Right attributes on your children to place them correctly.

Comment: Can you post your attempted RelativeLayout?

Comment: I've added it to the original question

Comment: Delete the line ```android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name"```. The combination of that and ```alignParentRight``` tells the system to place the start of the image immediately to the right of your text and to place the end at the right of the container. You can see that in your screenshot; the image takes up all remaining space. Alternatively, you could tell the text view to layout itself to the left of the imageview if you want to avoid the text and image overlapping. That will make the textview take up the remaining space. Hope that helps!